# How should my timer switch be wired?

Tags: electrical, switch, led, timer

I'm trying to add a timer switch to run my outdoor lights. There are two boxes side by side and no problems with the box on right (it has a red wire to switch to enable the hall light to be controlled from top or bottom of stairs).

The left box looks like this:

[image]

My issue: the included instructions don't say what to do with two lines out.   I presume this is not a three way?

I have one line (top) into the box, two lines out (bottom):

1. I ran the top line black (hot) to the black line of the "timer/programmable computer switch"
2. All whites are connected, top and bottom (when I took this line apart it was just a normal tumbler switch and no white line was in to the switch)
3. I have two bottom black (load) lines out, and they were twisted together.  I connected the red line from the programmable switch to these two black lines out.
4. There is a yellow line on the programmable switch, presumably not used here? (for three-way).
5. There's no other switch involved in these two bottom lines black, out.
6. The breaker doesn't get flipped when I turn it on, but there's no power to the programmable switch's LED.

What am I getting wrong?

Thanks for helps!

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do another picture or two, I cannot tell the wires from the shadow. Before disassembling put different colored tape on each wire and take a picture so you can put it back if you have to.

Comment: Added another couple pics!

Comment: Did you verify that line hot and load (or in/out) were what you thought they were? You may have them reversed, if your thought was incorrect. Quite common for the line hot to be spliced to feed line hot elsewhere on the circuit.

Comment: Face palm, Ecnerwal you're right... newbie mistake..

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, thanks for the fast response. From what I can tell the red and black on the bottom are connected to another 3 way switch (that switch will also control the lights) the top to the lights. Mark the top with a piece of tape so you can keep it seperate. The top would go to the identified leg of a timer switch in the directions it would be the one that does not go to the other switch. The other two would go to the travelers, red and black. If the new switch has a white it connects to the white wires. Let us know how you do.

Answer (score 0):

@Ecnerwal likely has the correct clue for this.  Unlike a standard switch, the timer is polarized.  If you attach the "line" wires to the red lead then it won't work.

The reason you might have 2 "line" wires is because the power needs to enter the box and then continue, unswitched, to another box.  Those 2 black wires would need to be spliced with the timer's black wire in a nut.

The lone black wire that you already connected to the timer could go to the lights and wouldn't be hot in that case except when the switch is closed (on).

I strongly suggest that you invest in a multi-tester and learn to use it to identify which wires are hot, especially doing so BEFORE removing any switch, ever.  It could save your life, or at least prevent an unwanted surprise.